# Sending Dynamic Emails through a Java Cron Job using Microsoft Graph

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, sendmail

I have a java (Spring boot) web service which does not have any UI.

I want to send a dynamic Email (created using Thymeleaf and injecting values from a database) using my web service on a daily Cron schedule, using Microsoft Graph and O365 APIs.

Right now I use SMTP to send emails, but I cannot use it anymore as that is no longer going to be supported by the O365 account that I am using.

I found the [SendMail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail) APIs on the Graph Documentation which looks pretty straightforward.

But, using the Graph AIPs requires you to create an Azure AD project first and use their Microsoft Identity platform - which I created.

Now, the problem is that most of the flows also require a user to manually login from a login window.

This is where things get complicated.

I do not have a place to show a Login window to any user from my web service, because it is just a backend service there is no UI. I intend to use a service account for sending the emails through the Application.

I found a [Daemon support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-app-types#daemons-and-server-side-apps) as well, but it seems to only support Python or .Net code.

Migrating my code from Java to either of those platforms just to be able to send emails 
does not feel like a good solution.

And, I'm not even sure if they even offer similar capabilities of sending dynamic emails like Java+Thylemeaf do?

Is there a way to be able to continue doing this using my existing code in Java?

If not, then as the worst case scenario, are there any libraries in Python which can allow me to send dynamic emails like thymeleaf does in Java?

Comment: According to the situation, you can use [Client Credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) flow to get access token then call the graph API with token. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to manually login from a login window, you can use the client credential flow.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) is the guide regarding how to access graph api without user.

Reference:

[msgraph-sdk-java-auth](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth) (You can choose to use [Client credential provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#client-credentials-provider))